# Resetting state after getDerivedStateFromError

Tags: reactjs

I'm using error boundaries in React and everything appears to be working as expected— `getDerivedStateFromError` gets called when there is an underlying error, and then I return a state to denote that there is an error.

But what happens after the component is no longer in an error state? I've tried using `getDerivedStateFromProps` to return a non-error state, but it ends up going into an infinite loop.

For example

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps()
    {
        return {
            hasError: false
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        return {
            hasError: true
        };
    }
```

It seems like React should only call one of those methods, not both. Any ideas on how to take a component in and out of an error state?